# Code loops after preg_match succeeds

Tags: php, preg-match

I am experiencing really weird code behavior. Essentially on a preg_match that should return true, the next statement does not execute itself. Let me demonstrate with my own code:

```
foreach($params as $param)
{
  error_log("processing $param");
  $doesInputContainBadCode = preg_match("/<script\b[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/m",$param);
  error_log("input contains bad code? :".$doesInputcontainBadCode);
  if($doesInputContainBadCode === 1) 
    error_log("process this input");
}
```

Say if my $params array consists of :

```
$params = {"first_name","last_name","middle_name","<script type="text/javascript">alert("javascript massacre");</script>", "whatever", "something else"}
```

This is what the error_log shows:

```
processing first_name
input contains bad code? : 0
processing last_name
input contains bad code? : 0
processing middle_name
input contains bad code? : 0
processing <script type="text/javascript">alert("javascript massacre");</script>
processing whatever
```

Notice how after processing the "javascript" containing parameter it skipped the error_log. It ought to have documented 
**input contains bad code ? : 1**
 **process this input**

However, none of that is documented. At the very least, I think it must log:

**input contains bad code ? :**

regardless of the result of the preg_match result. But it clearly did not and it is not just for this input, but any input where the preg_match succeeds this behavior is repeated.

[PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) states that preg_match returns either 1 or 0 depending on if it is a preg_match success or fail and false if there was an error. Not sure what is happening here, if anyone can point me in the right direction

Comment: Well, you aren't `break`ing out of your loop early....

Comment: Glancing at the title ("Code loops after preg_match succeeds") and at your `foreach` loop, there is no `break` statement within the loop. Therefore the loop will iterate through the entire `$param` array, whether or not your regular expression produces a match.

Comment: why should there be a break statement within my loop. Maybe the title is misleading, what I mean to say is that if the preg_match returned 1, then the subsequent code {error_log, if statement, error_log } are simply not being executed...

Comment: You're not accounting for the `false` return when `preg_match` errors.

Comment: preg_match returns 0 when there is no pattern. Why are you looking for a 1?

Comment: coz when there is a pattern it returns 1, that's what I am looking for

Comment: You're not escaping the double-quotes inside the javascript entry in the array.

Comment: This was a terrible question on my part, I was completely viewing the wrong results. The code is unfortunately working fine. I'll be closing this question

Comment: i mean fortunately working fine, I apologize for not being attentive enough but thanks to all for your time

Answer (score 1):

You should only test  `===` for an error

change log php 5.3.6    Returns FALSE if offset is higher than subject length.
above that is an error.

Warning

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

As you can see in your log, it never runs trough

```
if($doesInputContainBadCode === 1) 
   error_log("process this input");
}
```

You have to test, for example.

```
$param ="<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(\"javascript massacre\");</script>";
if (preg_match("/<script/i", $param)) {
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Output:

> A match was found.